# How can I edit over a NSString that is saved in an Array?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, nsstring, nsmutablearray, uitextview

I am saving multiple strings into an NSMutableArray and then setting each string into individual table view cells.

If a cell is selected, that string will be displayed in another view.

I'd like to be able to edit the string and save it again.

What's the best way to approach this?

Here's my save code:

```
- (IBAction)saveNote
{
    if (_noteView.aTextView.text == nil)
    {
        [_noteArray addObject:@""];

        Note * tempNote = [[Note alloc] init];
        _note = tempNote;

        [_savedNotesViewController.savedNoteArray addObject:tempNote];
        NSIndexPath * tempNotePath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[_savedNotesViewController.savedNoteArray count]-1 inSection:0];
        NSArray * tempNotePaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:tempNotePath];
        [_savedNotesViewController.noteTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:tempNotePaths withRowAnimation:NO];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"AddNote" object:nil];

     }
    else
    {
        [_noteArray addObject:self.noteView.aTextView.text];

        Note * tempNote = [[Note alloc] init];
        _note = tempNote;

        [_savedNotesViewController.savedNoteArray addObject:tempNote];
        NSIndexPath * tempNotePath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[_savedNotesViewController.savedNoteArray count]-1 inSection:0];
        //NSArray * tempNotePaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:tempNotePath];
        NSMutableArray * tempNotePaths = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:tempNotePath];
        [_savedNotesViewController.noteTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:tempNotePaths withRowAnimation:NO];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"AddNote" object:nil];

    }

    Note * myNote = [Note sharedNote];
    myNote.noteOutputArray = _noteArray;

}
```

Comment: If it's an NSString, you cannot "edit" it; the most you can do is replace it with a different string in the mutable array. If it's an NSMutableString, whatever is done to it, as seen by any other reference, is done to it, as seen by the mutable array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use NSMutableArray's method `[array replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:@"newString"]`

Comment: what would be the proper way to check if the text is equal to itself? Or would I need to do this?

Comment: @LukeIrvin- you can compair text by if(text1 isEqualToString:text2)